# Matching friend IDs with Graph API 2.2

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm getting started developing a facebook game and I'm hitting some problems in my understanding straight away. I'm hoping there's someone wise out there who can set me straight.

Like most games I want to be able to invite people to join, and then to know when they HAVE joined.

I am using Graph Api version 2.2 - as I understand that version 1.0 will be switched off come April 2015.    The issue I am getting to here is that the IDs / tags  are 'temporary' so there will be a problem matching them up.

Using this I can request a list of friends that already have the app installed. (great).  And I (should) receive back a list of IDs for these players.  I can then send them an AppRequest which will prompt them to load up the game.  (good so far).

At this point lets assume that one of more friends all load up the game.   Also assume that I have some back end processing on my server so each of these friends can say to the server  "I have the game loaded,  and I know 'my' ID these friend IDs".

In the game I'd then like to show a list of my current friends that actually have the game running - right now.   This will be possible because the server know's everyone's ID, and my ID, so it can say "here are the friends that you know..."

I hope you are still following me.

So can the Graph API 2.2  request both
(a) My own ID   (??)
(b) My friend's IDs.
  - which are matchable and expire at the same period of time.   (yes, I know this one is possible)

Is (a) possible?    An even if it is, is it an ID that is matchable to temporary friend IDs or is it of another type that can be used for different purposes. (for instance I read that the taggableFriend IDs cannot be used for appRequests).

If it is not possible can anyone explain to me the correct approach?

It seems to me that in the remaining days of Graph API 1.0 you don't have these problems as
(a) You can get your own ID using the FQL interface,
and  (b)  IDs are permanent so you can store them away in a database to save on these matching problems.
For instance, in Api 1.0 each running instance of the app would be able to get away with only requesting it's own facebook owner's ID.  (no friends).  - so long as friends had been asked at some point in the past.  Your own server would have enough info to be able to match them up and say "I knkow these IDs are your friends still".

But how do I do it in Graph API 2.0 ?

I won't have my game finished before April 2015 so there is really no point in using the older API.

Comment: I got so lost. I'm reading this back three times and I'm still lost. Writing an answer that hopefully gives you the gist of invitable_friends, me/friends, user_friends and app scoped ids.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a lot of stuff in here you already know but I think it would be best if I start from scratch just to get thoughts aligned.

**User ID**

There are currently two types of IDs for users available

- Global ID
- App scoped ID

Most if not all applications moving forward should be using the app scoped ID.

**User Friends**

As long as you request `user_friends` permission you will get a list of friends also using the application.

**Invitable Friends API**

As long as your app is a game on canvas you will be returned a full list of user's friends that you can invite via invite Tokens. These tokens are temporary and can be used in the  Request Dialog.

Now to your scenario, your game is running and the `/me/friends` list returns

```
    {
      "data": [
      ], 
      "summary": {
        "total_count": 5000
      }
    }
```

So, no friends are currently in the game. You invite friends using invite tokens from `/me/invitable_friends` and one of your friends join.

```
Recall `/me/friends`

{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "phwd friend lastname", 
      "id": "app-scoped-id-1"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me/friends..."
  }, 
  "summary": {
    "total_count": 5000
  }
}
```

So `app-scoped-id-1` (which will be a numeric) is the app scoped ID of your friend. This should not change.

So the ids that you will store are

- `/me?fields=id` the current player
- `/me/friends?fields=id` the player's friends who are also playing